# Как исправить ошибку #1064 limit 0, 50

Tags: mysql, sql

Версия mysql - 5.6

```
select * from users u 
left join privsroles pr 
on pr.id_priv = p.id_priv 
left join privs p 
left join roles r 
on u.id_role = 'pr.id_role' and u.id_role = 'r.id_role' 
where u.id_user = 2
```

Такой запрос выдаёт ошибку:

```
У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MySQL на предмет корректного синтаксиса около 'where u.id_user = 2 limit 0, 50' на строке 7
```

Как исправить?

Comment: Что то не разберусь - `limit 0, 50` присутсвует в Вашем коде? Откуда он появляется в сообщении ошибки?

Comment: @Валерій Грузицький, в том то и дело, что нет limit в коде, а выдаёт почему-то такую ошибку. Использую openserver

Comment: Как вы передаёте запрос в СУБД?

Comment: @word А какой апликухой пользуетесь?

Comment: Может там просто ";" в конце не хватает, а сообщения об ошибках часто просто вводят в заблуждение.

Comment: выбираю текущую базу в phpmyadmin, кликнув по ней справа в списке баз, потом сверху "Обзор, структура, SQL", выбираю SQL, и после ввода данного кода выдаёт вышеприведённую ошибку

Comment: @Николай Беляков, добавил ; ничего не изменилось

Comment: Пробуйте то, что советует @НиколайБеляков, вот еще здесь, что-то подобное рассматривается https://sqlinfo.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?id=2517

Comment: mysql query browser выдаёт эту же ошибку

Comment: ошибка была в объединении нескольких таблиц. Нужно было после каждого left join ставить условие on